# How can I view top contributors in a country by week?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, data-explorer, reputation-leagues

I just want to view the top contributors based on the reputation points by this week in a given country.

```
select row_number() over(order by reputation desc)
     , reputation
     , views
     , id as [User Link]
     , location
from users
where location like '%' + ##location:string## + '%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
order by reputation desc
```

I already have this query, and it displays all the top contributors in a given country. But it displays overall information, and I just want to sort it by the current week and want to display how many reputation points gain by each developer in the current week (not overall reputation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible with a relatively simple query like that one. The reason being that SEDE doesn't store reputation changes, only total reputation. You'd have to handcraft the reputation history (luckily, most of the events leading to reputation changes are available) which has been done for single users (e.g. [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1061705/reputation-changes-by-date) and [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882556/reputation-gained-until-a-certain-date)) but I'm not sure what happens if you do it for all Stack Overflow users from a single country.

(Also, Stack Overflow isn't refreshed yet, so this week is not available right now, but it will be in a few hours.)